# When I am debugging a C++ program with gdb, how can I print the value returned by a function I just stepped over?

Tags: c++, gdb

If I have some C++ program, e.g.:

```
#include <string>

std::string foo()
{
        return "bar";
}

int main()
{
        foo();
        return 0;
}
```

where there is a call to some function (e.g. `foo`) and I step over it **(and thus I cannot perform `finish` that would otherwise show the return value)**. If this function returns some value (e.g. of type `std::string`), how can I print the value returned by the function I just stepped over?

If the returned value is scalar, I can see the returned value in the appropriate register (i.e. in `$rax`  on Intel's x64 architecture).

If the returned value is structured value, in `rax` register I just see a pointer. **I failed to persuade `gdb` to pretty-print the underlying structured value to which `$rax` points.** I would be able to specify the C++ type by casing `$rax` to the appropriate pointer type as long as I do not have to cite mangled version of C++ types.

If, instead of just stepping over the function (with `next` gdb command) I "step in" in the function (with `step` gdb command) and then subsequently finishing the function (with `finish` gdb command), the returned value is pretty-printed and I can see it. This is a usable workaround, but I am interested in proper way, if it exists.

If `gdb` does not provide such command out of the box, is it possible to define some Python or Scheme macro that would (pretty-) print the returned value?

Comment: The linked "answer" describes a workaround that I have found (because I have read the linked answer). It does not answer the original question. I was asking, how can I see the value returned by a function to which I did not step into but only stepped over (and thus I does not make sense to perform the "finish" command they mention).

Comment: `p *(std::string *)$rax` will work in some cases. But when you're stopping at the statement after the statement containing a function call, rax may have been clobbered by other copy/move constructors, destructors, and calls to `_Unwind_Resume`.